# How to iterate the tags under same tag?

Tags: beautifulsoup

```
print(soup.table.thead.tr)

<tr>
<th scope="col"><span class="pl4">거래</span></th>
<th scope="col">종류</th>
<th scope="col">확인일자</th>
<th scope="col"> <span class="blind">현장확인 사진</span></th>
<th scope="col">매물명</th>
<th scope="col">


                        면적(㎡)



        </th>
<th scope="col">층</th>
<th class="align_r" scope="col">매물가(만원)</th>
<th scope="col">연락처</th></tr>
In [ ]:
```

I have this result from beautifulSoup and I want to get the value of th tags under tr tags. How can I get this list or iterate? I don't want to use find_all() function. Because, the html is too huge to search so that I do need another alternative. 
    ​

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Beautiful-soup has generator for huge data:

[Document](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#contents-and-children):

```
childGenerator() -> children
nextGenerator() -> next_elements
nextSiblingGenerator() -> next_siblings
previousGenerator() -> previous_elements
previousSiblingGenerator() -> previous_siblings
recursiveChildGenerator() -> descendants
parentGenerator() -> parents
```

you can use `children` generator:

```
for th in soup.table.thead.tr.children:
    pass
```

Comment: Can you give more explanation? I can't understand yet.